# Can I display prints using PySimpleGUI?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I am using PySimpleGUI to build a GUI for my application. I am trying to print out on screen some messages for the user through a `Listbox` but when I call the `window[].update()` lines the print out is not showing by line but putting each character on a new line. I am not sure if `Listbox` is the function that I should be using or if there is another function better suited for what I want to do.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import os, sys

file_list_column = [
    [sg.Text('File Name: '), sg.In(size = (25, 1), enable_events = True, key = '-ID-')],
    [sg.Text('File Location: '), sg.In(size = (25, 1), enable_events = True, key = '-FOLDER-'),sg.FolderBrowse()],
    [sg.Button('Create Location')],
    [sg.Listbox(values = [], enable_events = True, size = (40, 20), key = '-UPDATES-')],]

layout = [[sg.Column(file_list_column)],
          [sg.Button('Close')]]

window = sg.Window('Test', layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == 'Close' or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
        break
        
    if event == 'Create Location':
        try:
            os.makedirs(os.path.join(values['-FOLDER-'], values['-ID-']))
            window['-UPDATES-'].update(str('Folder location created.'))
        except:
            window['-UPDATES-'].update(str('Folder location NOT created.'))

window.close()
```

The string I want to display to the user is placing each character on its own line.

[image]

Comment: The update method seems to take an iterable. You could try `window['-UPDATES-'].update(['Folder location created.'])`

Comment: That did it. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you should use `sg.Multiline`. (1) with options `reroute_stdout=True, reroute_stderr=True`, you can use python print statement; (2) Using method `print` of `sg.Multiline` to print; (3) Using method `update` of `sg.Multiline` to change some of settings of `sg.Multiline` element.

Comment: `sg.Listbox` is the element to show a list of items for selection, not for printing.

Comment: As above sg.Listbox is showing string as a list as internally String is a list in Python. like so a='Hello', access like a list print(a[1]), here it is adding each char into a list